Failed to run jobs on GitLab Runner with docker-autoscaler in Azure
I'm trying to configure a GitLab Runner instance with the docker-autoscaler executor with the fleeting plugin using an Azure Scale Set.
I've created a managed Azure VM image based on a VM with: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Docked installed, added the azureuser to the docker group and configured Docker to start on boot with systemctl.
So far I could create the Scale Set and configure my runner. When the runner starts, it would update the Scale Set (I can see new instances starting up), but then this error comes up and the job won't even start:
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at http://internal.tunnel.invalid. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:951:0s)

What am I missing?
This are my versions:

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Docker version 26.1.3, build b72abbb
GitLab Runner Version:      17.0.0
Git revision: 44feccdf
Git branch:   17-0-stable
GO version:   go1.21.9
Built:        2024-05-16T13:46:14+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

And this is my Runner config.toml:
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "My Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  id = 123123123
  token = "glrt-Some-Token"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-03-28T14:02:04Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker-autoscaler"

  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0

  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/certs/client"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
    services_limit = -1

  # Autoscaler config
  [runners.autoscaler]
    plugin = "azure" # for >= 16.11, ensure you run `gitlab-runner fleeting install` to automatically install the plugin

    # for versions < 17.0, manually install the plugin and use:
    # plugin = "fleeting-plugin-azure"

    capacity_per_instance = 1
    max_use_count = 1
    max_instances = 10

    [runners.autoscaler.plugin_config] # plugin specific configuration (see plugin documentation)
      name = "gitlab-runner-scale-set"
      subscription_id = "SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
      resource_group_name = "gitlab-runner"

    [runners.autoscaler.connector_config]
      username = "azureuser"
      password = "SOME-PASSWORD"
      use_static_credentials = true
      timeout = "10m"
      use_external_addr = true

    [[runners.autoscaler.policy]]
      idle_count = 1
      idle_time = "10m0s"


check that the listen is in correct socket and try checking docker is running and able to access the VM within scale set @JoaquínL.Robles

@JoaquínL.Robles, were you ever able to get this working? I'm hitting the same issue.

Sorry @RandallT. I just gave up

For me, the problem was a permission issue. The autoscaler config user (e.g. 'azureuser' above) needed to be added to the docker group on the VMs, like
sudo usermod -aG docker azureuser

Link: https://documentation.cloud-runner.com/docs/troubleshooting/cannot-connect-docker/#2-insufficient-permissions

Thanks for the work, I'll give it a try again
